# how to connection string in for ... in ... ? (python)

Tags: python, string

I'm a c coder, but python is differrent, I met a problem about this

```
items = [
     ["/ank/homepage.py","Home"],
     ["/ank/package.py","Packages"],
     ["/status.py","Status"],
     ["/task.py","Task"],
     ["/report.py","Report"]
]

static_html='<table id="main_nav" align="center"><tr>'

for each_item in items:
    if each_item in items:
        if isinstance(each_item, list):
            static_html=  static_html + '<td><a href=" ', each_item[0], ' "> ', each_item[1], ' </a></th> '

static_html+='</tr></table>'

print static_html
```

then,the IDE send me an error /usr/bin/python2.7

```
/home/tsuibin/code/aps/dxx/test_tmp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tsuibin/code/aps/dxx/test_tmp.py", line 39, in <module>
    printMainNavigation()
  File "/home/tsuibin/code/aps/dxx/test_tmp.py", line 20, in printMainNavigation
    static_html=  static_html + '<td><a href=" ', each_item[0], ' "> ', each_item[1], ' </a></th> '
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: someone formated your code, and now you messed it up again :) (It's fine now)

Answer (score 5):

You are putting commas in your string concatenation:

```
static_html=  static_html + '<td><a href=" ', each_item[0], ' "> ', each_item[1], ' </a></th> '
```

and Python thus sees those elements as a tuple (`str0 + (str1, str2, str3)`). Use `+` instead:

```
static_html=  static_html + '<td><a href=" ' + each_item[0] + ' "> ' + each_item[1] + ' </a></th> '
```

Better yet, use string formatting:

```
static_html += '<td><a href="{0[0]}"> {0[1]} </a></th> '.format(each_item)
```

When concatenating a series of strings in python, it's actually going to be faster to use a `list()` as intermediary. Build the list, then use `''.join()` to get the output:

```
static_html = ['<table id="main_nav" align="center"><tr>']
for each_item in items:
     static_html.append('<td><a href="{0[0]}"> {0[1]} </a></th> '.format(each_item))

static_html.append('</tr></table>')
static_html = ''.join(static_html)
```

Note that you don't need to *test* for `each_item in items` at all, you just got the item from the list in the loop already. That's just extra work that doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 4):

Other people have pointed out the cause of your error message. I've taken the liberty of re-writing the code a bit. The main thing I have done is avoid string concatenation - in Python, strings are immutable so concatenation requires the creation of an entire new string. A common method to avoid this is to put the fragments of the string into a list, and then use the [join()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method of a string to join all the elements of the list together.

The other major change is to use the [string.format()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method to create the fragments.

```
items = [
     ["/ank/homepage.py","Home"],
     ["/ank/package.py","Packages"],
     ["/status.py","Status"],
     ["/task.py","Task"],
     ["/report.py","Report"]
]

# Start a list of fragments with the start of the table.
html_fragments = [
    '<table id="main_nav" align="center"><tr>'
]

for item in items:
    # No need for the 'if item in items' here - we are iterating
    # over the list, so we know its in the list.
    #
    # Also, this ifinstance() test is only required if you cannot
    # guarantee the format of the input. I have changed it to allow
    # tuples as well as lists.
    if isinstance(item, (list, tuple)):
        # Use string formatting to create the row, and add it to
        # the list of fragments.
        html_fragments.append('<td><a href="{0:s}">{1:s}</a></td>'.format(*item))

# Finish the table.
html_fragments.append ('</tr></table>')

# Join the fragments to create the final string. Each fragment
# will be separated by a newline in this case. If you wanted it
# all on one line, change it to ''.join(html_fragments).
print '\n'.join(html_fragments)
```

And the output I got:

```
<table id="main_nav" align="center"><tr>
<td><a href="/ank/homepage.py">Home</a></td>
<td><a href="/ank/package.py">Packages</a></td>
<td><a href="/status.py">Status</a></td>
<td><a href="/task.py">Task</a></td>
<td><a href="/report.py">Report</a></td>
</tr></table>
```